How to get @FocusState property to work when TextField is on .sheet
I have the following simple code which places a Button on a View and when tapped, presents a TextField on a .sheet:
struct TestView: View
{
    @State private var sheetIsPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var userInput: String = ""
    @FocusState private var textFieldIsFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Button("Hello")
        {
            self.sheetIsPresented = true
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$sheetIsPresented)
        {
            HStack
            {
                Text("Name:")
                TextField("Enter name", text: self.$userInput).focused(self.$textFieldIsFocused)
                .onChange(of: self.textFieldIsFocused)
                {
                    print("textFieldIsFocused")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When the TextField is activated and the keyboard appears, the .onChange of is not occurring and "textFieldIsFocused" is not being printed to the console. However, when I move the code for the TextField out of the.sheet and onto the View itself, it works perfectly fine. How can I get this FocusState property to work when the TextField is on the .sheet?

It works when you factor out the sheet content into a separate view:
struct TestViewSheet: View {
    @Binding var userInput: String
    @FocusState private var textFieldIsFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Name:")
            TextField("Enter name", text: $userInput)
                .focused($textFieldIsFocused)
                .onChange(of: textFieldIsFocused) {
                    print("textFieldIsFocused")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var sheetIsPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var userInput: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello") {
            sheetIsPresented = true
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented) {
            TestViewSheet(userInput: $userInput)
        }
    }
}


Thank you so much, that definitely fixes the problem as I stated it. Wondering though, if you send in TextFieldIsFocused from TestView to TestViewSheet as a binding, does that work for you? For some reason that's still not working for me.

@SerPounce I tried using a binding for the FocusState (specifically: FocusState<Bool>.Binding>) but couldn't get it to work either. The internal workings of SwiftUI must require that the FocusState variable belongs to the same tree. Not able to explain any better because I really don't know the exact reason and haven't seen it documentated either. Thanks for accepting the answer anyway!
